# Union which excludes values from the first table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, birt

The origional problem I am attempting to solve is that I need to show all rows from a specific "joined" table. However these are sometimes blank with no totals and normally would not show (think categories and counts for each).

So what I am attempting to do is union to a "0 value" data set to show all categories. However when I do the union it shows a 0 value row, as well as the normal data. Here is an example..

```
SELECT category_name, COUNT(files_number)
FROM files
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.category_id = files.category_id

UNION 

SELECT category_name, 0
FROM categories
```

This will give me a result set that looks similar to this:

```
category_name | value
----------------------
open file     | 0
open file     | 23
closed file   | 0
```

Is there any way to remove duplicate zero value entries? Please not there is also a complex WHERE clause in the actual query, so avoiding duplication on it is preferred.

Comment: I forgot this in the original question - but there is some restrictions I face because this is implemented using BIRT. As such the "correct" answer for me may reflect these limitations placed by BIRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you are doing left join and union..

You can do below to remove duplicates,wrap your query and do group by

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT category_name, COUNT(files_number)
FROM files
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.category_id = files.category_id
UNION 
SELECT category_name, 0
FROM categories
)
select categoryname,sum(aggcol)
from cte
group by 
category
```

Comment: I had to make a slight modification to this (as my tool - BIRT - does not let me do everything in SQL-Server. However it seems to be working and saved me having to change any of the query. Looking into it a bit more but this might work (more-or-less).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to select all categories from the categories table, and LEFT JOIN onto the file counts (grouped by category_id).

```
SELECT c.category_name, ISNULL(fc.FileCount, 0) AS FileCount
FROM categories c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT category_id, COUNT(files_number) AS FileCount
        FROM files
        GROUP BY category_id
    ) fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
```

**Edit**
If you want to reverse the query, you could do it something like this, using a RIGHT OUTER JOIN - so every category from categories table is returned, regardless of if there are any files for it:

```
SELECT c.category_name, COUNT(f.category_id) AS FileCount
FROM files f
    RIGHT JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = f.category_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: I am not sure if it matters for your example - but the query (which I would rather not have to rewrite as it is large and complex) is reversed - E.g. select files, join categories. I also have multiple sum/avg/count running on this query. Do you think it will still work with the suggested fix?